# Creating feature sets and invoice labels for Custom Model Training using EasyOCR

Tags: machine-learning

We are trying to use EasyOCR for creating custom model for Invoice Data Recognition. However the contents from the easy OCR aren't helping us much. We want to create a custom dataset using collected sample Invoice images. We have now the bounding boxes (top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right) and the classification of each text. However I am confused as to how these should be combined to create the training/test data.

Should it be of the format (X_max,X_min,Ymax,Ymin,$RecognizedText$,$Class$)? Where class is something of the format
0 Document_Title
1 Invoice_Number
2 Invoice_Date
...
...
...
etc

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.